# Unable to login to 2020 Winter Bash page

Tags: support, login, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I'm trying to log in to the [2020 Winter Bash](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) page. After clicking the "Log in or Sign up" it returns the below message:

> `redirect_uri` is not under the registered domain for this application

Is it the expected behavior? The current year's Winter Bash has not yet started, so I hope we can log in to the previous year's.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: "redirect_uri is not under the registered domain for this application"]

Comment: The registered domain seems to have been changed to `winterbash2021.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Winter Bash application has been updated to point to this year's domain in preparation and it is no longer possible to login to the previous site. The old Winter Bash site will be removed momentarily - literally as soon as someone processes the request to remove the old domain bindings.